# How do I check for new files in various source folders and copy them over to a destination folder?

Tags: python, database, automation, copy, shutil

I'm relatively new to Python here! For a machine that I use at work, it typically runs for several hours so during that time period, I would like to write a program in Python that will check various source folders for new files and automatically copy them over to a destination location *while* the machine is running. Normally, we would have to manually copy these files over to the destination after the machine is done running which can be tedious because it takes a very long time, so it would be great to automate this during the run time.

I've managed to piece together some Python code that allows me copy over files from different sources to a single destination once it's run however I'm struggling with the automation process where the program would continuously check for new, completed files itself during the run time (instead of the user having to run the program after the run time). I've included the code below and was thinking of using both a while loop and importing a time module to check at specific time intervals? Any advice/tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
import shutil
import os

DESKTOP = 'D:/Users/Andrew/Desktop'
MUSIC = 'D:/Users/Andrew/Music'
VIDEOS = 'D:/Users/Andrew/Videos'
DESTINATION = 'D:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/Destination'

for files in os.listdir(DESKTOP):
    if files.lower().endswith('.xlsx'):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(DESKTOP, files), DESTINATION)

for files in os.listdir(MUSIC):
    if files.lower().endswith('.pptx'):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(MUSIC, files), DESTINATION)

for files in os.listdir(VIDEOS):
    if files.lower().endswith('.docx'):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(VIDEOS, files), DESTINATION)
```

Comment: the concept of *new* files is not anywhere in your code atm. To do that you would need to create a *screenshot* of your directories and their files and then compare that to the new screenshots you will be taking say every 5 min.

Comment: Can the files change and move around as well? Things like this can get pretty tricky.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis How can I go about starting to write code that would capture screenshots of my directories/files in order to compare them to previous screenshots? I'm not too familiar with this method.

Comment: @Grimmy Change and move around as in being replaced by new files?

Comment: @AndrewNguyen Search for "rsync algorithm". I'm sure there are some python projects for this already.